# Node.js createWriteStream fixed size

Tags: node.js, web-audio-api

It might be a naive question but I can´t still find a solution.

This is my code, in node:

```
var AudioContext = require('web-audio-api').AudioContext;
var context = new AudioContext();
context.outStream = require('fs').createWriteStream("out.txt");
```

I need this "out.txt" for audiocontext to work, I don´t know if there´s a better solution, the problem is that "out.txt" start growing up to infinite and that´s not what I need, I need to leave the stream open restricting the size of this `buffer`. I need all this to use another library:

```
var WAAClock = require('waaclock/index');
var clock = new WAAClock(context);
clock.start();
var event = clock.callbackAtTime(function () {
    //called each beatDur value
    console.log("tik");

}, 0).repeat(beatDur).tolerance({
    late: 100
});
```

Any solution?

Comment: Why do you need to set outStream? I don't think you necessarily need to set it (though I haven't actually used node-web-audio-api). It's supposed to send to the computer's speakers if you don't set it. Where do you want the audio to go?

Comment: Actually I don't need to send the audio anywhere, but WAAClock needs the webaudio context to work, and the webaudio context throw an error if I don't set an outstream.

Comment: So you're just using WAAClock as a way to set a timer? Why not use setTimeout or setInterval? The whole point of WAAClock is to schedule events in sync with audio.

Comment: Because I am using WAAClock also in the frontend and waaclock is a library dealing with the inconsistency of javascript timers

Comment: I have doubts about whether WAAClock is actually more consistent than standard JavaScript timers, but if you have measured it, I'd be interested to hear how good it actually is. You can probably use a /dev/null type of stream like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dev-null).

Comment: I used your suggestion, but not with your library that doesn´t work properly with WAAClock, instead with vstream. Unfortunately it is inconsistent, the clock is not stable as in the brower version of the same script. Now I am trying as you suggested with a simple setInterval, but I noticed that using setInterval with the same configuration lead to different results in the browser and in the server: for an interval of 100ms I get a medium result of 109 in the server vs 101 in the browser.